# Config file for Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm currently trying to use a file to config my makefile.

This is what i have done

```
NAME        =   test
OBJS        =   $(SRCS_NAMES:.c=.o)
SRCS_DIR    =   sources/

function = echo main.c test.c
#function where i parse my file
#i use a makefile function cause i need to pass regex as parameters

all : $(NAME)

parse :
    $(eval SRCS_NAMES = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), $(shell $(call function))))

-include parse

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
    gcc -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)
```

I don't understand why the .o aren't build.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `parse` rule doesn't create an actual makefile, so make will not restart parsing after it's finished processing the rule, and `OBJS` will be empty during make's first phase.

You can either create a makefile

```
parse:
    @echo SRCS_NAMES = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), $(shell $(call function))) > $@
```

Or just set `SRCS_NAMES` directly in the body of your current makefile

```
SRCS_NAMES  = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), $(shell $(call function)))
```